# Resolve dependencies except submodules

Tags: java, maven

I have a Java Maven project that has some external dependencies, as well as submodules that depend on other submodules.

Example:
|- pom.xml (modules: A, B)
|- moduleA
....|- pom.xml (dependencies: `org.json`, `com.myproject.moduleb`)
|- moduleB
....|- pom.xml (dependencies: `org.apache.logging.log4j`)

I want to separate packaging into two stages:
1) Resolve external dependencies (so that this step can later be cached; I'm running Maven in a Docker container)
2) Run "package" and resolve the remaining submodule dependencies, compile submodule jars.
If I run `mvn go-offline` and then `mvn package`, the first command fails because it expects jars from my submodules. Haven't found options for `go-offline` that do what I need.

What is the right approach here?

Comment: If you have a multi module build and your build via `mvn package` fails than there is something wrong...

Comment: What about running `mvn package`? This should fill your local repository with the desired artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the option `-N`?

From the [Maven CLI Options Reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html)

> -N,--non-recursive    Do not recurse into sub-projects

This stops maven from going into sub-modules.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want the local maven repo/cache to be filled in the first build step to make subsequent builds faster. I created 3 sample modules, parent:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.grau.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

child1:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>net.grau.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and child2:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>net.grau.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The child poms are located in the default subdirectories:

|- pom.xml (modules: A, B)
|- child1
....|- pom.xml (dependencies:org.json)
|- child2
....|- pom.xml (dependencies:org.apache.logging.log4j)

Then I run `mvn dependency:go-offline` in the directory containing the parent pom. This downloads all dependencies required to package the modules, but does NOT build the modules or complains about them being missing. After this step jar files for org.json and org.apache.logging.log4j have been downloaded and stored in the local maven repo/cache. Unfortunately, a few maven core pom files (and the transitive dependencies therein) are not downloaded during this step so a `mvn -o package` will fail. This can be worked around by building a very simple dummy module to cause maven to download the missing dependencies. This is the state you want to cache. After that `mvn -o package` using the parent pom works.